# Get the value from a command in make file

Tags: shell, makefile, sh, gnu-make, gnu

I have a script, which works okay, which I use as follows to get some value:

```
tmpDir=$(xtr execute run)
```

in the command code itself I print the value like

```
fmt.Print("the dir is: ",dir)
```

and then when I put echo in the script I get the value of `tmpDir`

Now I need to switch to use **make file** and I do it exactly like this
and I don't get any value in the `tmpDir`. What am I missing here?

Here is the makefile

```
all: app app_2
    PROJ_DIR=$(PWD)
# Create folder for build artifacts
    DIR=$(xtr execute run)
.PHONY: app
app:
    @echo $(DIR)

       ....
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem did you find?

Comment: @Flimzy-  This is what I try but I got empty value in `makefile`

Comment: @Flimzy - In the script is working but not in makefile for exact the same code...

Comment: @Flimzy - I use tabs and I was able to execute it , this is not the problem :)

Comment: What is `xtr`?  Is that the command you're trying to run?  If so you should be using [`$(shell xtr execute run)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function).

Comment: @G.M. - can you post it as answer, and i'l try it since `DIR=$(xtr execute run)` and  echo is not working, but maybe I miss something

Comment: @G.M. - and yes this is a command of cli that if you execute it from terminal is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make recipes are expanded by make first and then passed to the shell. So, your `DIR=$(xtr execute run)` is first expanded by make but as there is no make variable named `xtr execute run`, it expands as `DIR=`.

But it is not your only problem: the variable named `DIR` in your recipe is a shell variable, not a make variable. It exists only in the context of the shell that make will spawn to execute this part (and only this one) of your recipe:

```
DIR=$(xtr execute run)
```

As there is nothing else in this shell invocation, it is useless. It is like you were spawning a new shell, execute `DIR=` in it, and exit.

The `DIR` variable in the recipe of `app`  is another variable, with the same name. Again, make expands it before passing the recipe part to the shell but as there is no such make variable, it expands as:

```
echo
```

You have a similar problem with `$(PWD)`: it is expanded by make and as there is no such make variable, it expands as the empty string. You could probably use `CURDIR`, instead, which is a built-in make variable. But remember that `PROJ_DIR` is a shell variable that will exist only for this single line part of your recipe...

Instead of all this you could try:

```
DIR := $(shell xtr execute run)
PROJ_DIR := $(CURDIR)

all: app app_2

.PHONY: app
app:
    @echo $(DIR)
```

Here, `DIR` and `PROJ_DIR` are make variables that are assigned once (note the `:=`, it is important) when make parses the makefile. From now on, they can be used in recipes where they will be expanded by make before the part of the recipe is actually passed to the shell for execution.